raspberry-pi as media player server device
I wan't to use my raspberry-pi 4b as a media player server -device, meaning that raspberry has no keyboard or mouse, but it is connected to to my TV with HDMI and also connected to network. I use ubuntu-workstation with keyboard, mouse and display and run Chrominum Web Browser in ubuntu and find a nice live video to play, watch and listen. It can by played and voice listened in my ubuntu-workstation, but I wan't to watch and listen video in my television. Raspberry is connected to television, ubuntu is connected to raspberry. How the trick can be done?
Devices are connected like this:
                   network             hdmi
keyboard - ubuntu <-------> raspberry ------> television
mouse -
headphones -
display -

Now I have installed X in raspberry, but not desktop-applications: Adding PIXEL/GUI to Raspbian Lite, no Xinit. I know that in principle it is possible to define X-display in my ubuntu pointing to raspberry and if I set that to my chromium-browser which is in full screen mode, I can see video on my TV?, but there is no voice, and I need also to transfer voice to my TV. How to do that? What are concrete commands I have to run in my ubuntu and raspberry (with ssh) should I install something to transfer voice from ubuntu to raspberry?
